# How Do I Reduce Noise Floor in a Booth With No EQ

Tags: sound-design, noise, equipment, room-treatment, booth

I need to submit a raw recording to an audio engineer with no editing for a demo. The noise floor of my recording must be at least -40 RMS. When I do not speak, the RMS is at -60 but when I do speak, the RMS shoots up to -25. I also must have my levels set between -6 and -12. I'm recording in a 4 by 4 vocal booth purchased from Vocalbooth.com (I'm aware that I should've bought a smaller booth to maximize sound quality but didn't realize this until it was too late). I'm recording on Rode Mic attached to a Focusrite Scarlett. I'm also using Twisted Wave on a MacBook Pro. I have added a moving blanket to the bottom of the booth.

This is my first time submitting a question to Stack Exchange so I apologize if the formatting is off. I'm also not an audio engineer and am sorry if I got some terminology wrong. Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: I'd double-check the measurements. During your speech, pause for 10 seconds, keep breathing but otherwise remain silent. Re-test the noise floor. (You could check again whilst holding your breath, just to eliminate you being a 'noisy breather' ;)